# To use or not to use a SwingWorker versus a regular Thread

Tags: java

I have a start and stop button. I want to be able to start and stop a task as many times as the user wants to. I was able to get this working properly with a regular thread by doing a wait() when the stop button was pushed and then a notify() when the start button was pushed to start the thread again. This worked great. However... I extended thread. My boss told me to never extend thread and that I should use a SwingWorker. But I noticed that a SwingWorker can only be executed once. Or can it be executed more than once in the same session..?? Can somebody help me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new **instance** of your SwingWorker each time you want to run the logic.  Personally, I don't see much benefit to SwingWorker for your problem as you described it.  Not to say it won't do fine...

Answer (score 3):

You very rarely need to extend `Thread`. What you should do is pass a `Runnable` to a `Thread` constructor.

For my tastes `SwingWorker` adds too much coupling to code, and should be left to demos where it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a SwingWorker for what you doing. SwingWorker is used for cases when you have to run something in background thread, update your GUI (like progress) without locking i down.

What you did already is fine.